# How do I change the command prompt using a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash

My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 21.04. I am trying to change my command prompt with a script I made, called `recording.sh`. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash  

echo -n "are you recording? yes(1)/no(0)"  
read VAR  

if [ $VAR -eq 1 ]; then  
       PS1="\[\033[38;5;2m\]Hazardous-potato@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]:\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;4m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]: \[$(tput sgr0)\]"  
else  
       PS1="\[\033[38;5;2m\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]:\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;4m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]: \[$(tput sgr0)\]"  
fi
```

I expect my command prompt to change from:

```
sterling@The-beast~:
```

to

```
Hazardous-potato@The-beast~:
```

when I run the above script, but, instead, it just stays the same.

Comment: When you change a variable in a bash file it only changes for the duration of the bash file. It has no effect once the file has run.

Comment: is there a way to run it until the terminal closes?

Comment: To take effect in the parent interactive shell you would need to *source* the file rather than run it

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @steeldriver that's the answer! prefix the bash script with `source`. I have seen the `source` used before, now it is clear to me what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sourced the file and lead bash into the file to execute it when the terminal opens. I sourced it at the end of the `.bashrc` file:

```
. /home/sterling/recording.sh
```

Comment: You don't need to put it in the `.bashrc` file if you don't want to run it every time you open a terminal. You can run it when you want in any terminal by typing `. ./recording.sh`. Note two dots separated by a space in the front before the `/`. Alternately you can type `source ./recording.sh`.